# Optimisation tool in R to find the input parameter of function that minimises output value?

Tags: r, optimization

I wish to find an optimisation tool in R that lets me determine the value of an input parameter (say, a specific value between 0.001 and 0.1) that results in my function producing a desired output value.

My function takes an input parameter and computes a value. I want this output value to exactly match a predetermined number, so the function outputs the absolute of the difference between these two values; when they are identical, the output of the function is zero.

I've tried `optimize()`, but it seems to be set up to minimise the input parameter, not the output value. I also tried `uniroot()`, but it produces the error `f() values at end points not of opposite sign`, suggesting that it doesn't like the fact that increasing/decreasing the input parameter reduces the output value up to a point, but going beyond that point then increases it again.

Apologies if I'm missing something obvious here—I'm completely new to optimising functions.

Comment: "I'm completely new to optimising functions." It shows unfortunately. You should start with reading some introductionary texts to the topic.

Comment: Could you point me in the right direction? I had done a fair amount of background research, and it doesn't seem to be that obvious.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed you are missing something obvious:-) It's very obvious how you should/could formulate your problem.

Assuming the function that must equal a desired output value is `f`.
Define a function `g` satisfying

```
g <- function(x) f(x) - output_value
```

Now you can use `uniroot` to find a zero of `g`. But you must provide endpoints that satisfy the requirements of `uniroot`. I.e. the value of `g` for one endpoint must be positive and the value of `g` for the other endpoint must be negative (or the other way around).

Example:

```
f <- function(x) x - 10
g <- function(x) f(x) - 8
```

then

```
uniroot(g,c(0,20))
```

will do what you want but

```
uniroot(g,c(0,2))
```

will issue the error message `values at end points not of opposite sign`.

You could also use an optimization function but then you want to minimize the function `g`. To set you straight: `optimize` does *not* minimize the input paramater. Read the help thoroughly.

Comment: I hadn't considered using a function within a function, so not that obvious to me, I'm afraid. Thanks!